# VB.Net OutOfMemoryException Substring

Tags: xml, string, vb.net

I have a problem in my loop. I split a text document into x smaller ones. The problem is that the documents are getting bigger, even though they should be the same big. When the third or the fourth Textdocument gets created i am getting a SystemOutofMemory Exception (which is logical).

Anybody who see a Mistake in my Loop ?

I already tried

```
 Sub splitFile()
    Dim SplitNumber As Long = Textlaenge / Splitanzahl
    Dim endindex As Long = 0

    For i As Int64 = 1 To Splitanzahl
        Dim nab As String = inhalt.Substring(endindex, SplitNumber * i)
        Dim index As Long = inhalt.IndexOf("><", nab.Count)

        Dim FinalString As String = inhalt.Substring(endindex, index + 1)

        endindex = index + 1

        If i = 1 Then

            FinalString = FinalString & "</ifapRohdaten>"
        Else
            'FinalString = "TEST" & FinalString & "</ifapRohdaten>"
        End If

        If i = Splitanzahl Then
            'FinalString = "TEST" & FinalString
        End If
```

## Region "Textdatei Schreiben"

```
        'Hier wird der text in eine Textdatei geschrieben und unter dem 
         angegebenden Pfad abgespeichert
        Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter
        'Pass the file path and the file name to the StreamWriter 
          constructor.
        objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\jd\Desktop\" & "Artikel" & i & ".xml")

        'Write a line of text.
        objStreamWriter.Write(FinalString)

        'Close the file.
        objStreamWriter.Close()

        objStreamWriter = Nothing
    Next
```

[image]

Comment: I already checked that the String is long enough

Comment: You would have to handle a single line at a time, instead of trying to keep the entire XML file content in a memory.  That requires a significant rewrite, unlikely that an SO contributor will do the job for you.  Or just use Project > Properties > Compile tab > untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I unticked "Prefer 32-bit" and it works much longer but still not till the end.

Comment: What are you trying to do, can you give an example of the input file and your desired output? There may be a much more easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: My Input is an XML File and i want to split the XML File into smaller ones. So the Output are for example 4 smaller ones.